# Run spotless:check without pulling maven dependencies in Github Actions

Tags: java, maven, github-actions, google-artifact-registry, spotless

I am trying to set a Github Action to check spotless.

My actions.yml

```
name: Java CI with Maven

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'
          cache: maven
      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn clean
```

In my pom.xml I have set spotless to trigger with clean lifecycle.

pom.xml (in spotless plugin):

```
<executions>
  <execution>
    <goals>
      <goal>check</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>clean</phase>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

Full pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.sample.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>demo</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-firestore</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-secretmanager</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.internal</groupId>
            <artifactId>internal</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.10</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>artifact-registry</id>
            <url>artifactregistry://maven.pkg.dev/gcp-project-name/private-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.9.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate-the-git-infos</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>validateRevision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <includeOnlyProperties>
                        <property>git.branch</property>
                        <property>git.commit.id</property>
                        <property>git.closest.tag.name</property>
                    </includeOnlyProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>
                            <includes>
                                <include>src/**/*.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <trimTrailingWhitespace/>
                            <endWithNewline/>
                            <indent>
                                <spaces>true</spaces>
                                <spacesPerTab>4</spacesPerTab>
                            </indent>
                        </format>
                    </formats>
                    <java>
                        <removeUnusedImports />
                        <googleJavaFormat>
                            <version>1.15.0</version>
                            <style>AOSP</style>
                            <reflowLongStrings>true</reflowLongStrings>
                        </googleJavaFormat>
                    </java>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.2.Final</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.24</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.artifactregistry</groupId>
                <artifactId>artifactregistry-maven-wagon</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.4</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>

</project>
```

Everything works as it should, except all dependent JARs are being pulled almost every time(cache helps if commits are close together). This is a problem because the project has dependencies from private GCP artifact repo, which the runner cannot access.

This causes what should be a 30s runtime to almost 3 minutes repeatedly attempting to connect to the private maven repository.

---

I have tried removing the cache for maven, changed to `mvn spotless:check` hoping to directly trigger spotless but the runner keeps trying to pull the dependencies.

---

What maven lifecycle should I use to avoid pulling the JARs (atleast from the private repo). Is there a better way to run spotless and speed this up?

Comment: Repositories should be defined in settings.xml, not Pom.xml

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Can't we customise repository list per project using pom.xml ? https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html#downloading-from-a-remote-repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe you have misconfigured something in project pom.

First of all, `spotless-maven-plugin` does not expect any dependency resolution to occur prior it's execution, so the only two things need to happen:

- maven needs to construct project object model, in order to do that it needs to resolve parents and dependency management (resolve imports)
- maven needs to download plugin and it's dependencies

If you have configured your project like:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>GCP</id>
        <name>GCP</name>
        <url>some url</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

you got into typical maven trap: repositories configured via `pom.xml` or `settings.xml` always take precedence over `maven central`, that means that when maven needs to download something it tries to use configured repository first and only in case of failure it will try `maven central`. The options are:

1. add `maven central` first to your repository list
2. activate your private repositories via maven profile

Comment: Still learning about Maven and profiles that you mentioned. Moved the private repository and a plugin that would be need for spotless and it solved this issue. Thanks. I looked past that the jars being pulled were plugins, etc. My understanding was clean doesn't pull anything (atleast for me locally, probably cached?) so was stumped why `mvn clean` was pulling from the repositories. Any good resource where I can learn more about maven in a simple way would be much appreciated.

Comment: @BharathYes well, your understanding of maven seems to be wrong. `clean`, `compile`, `package`, etc - all of them are lifecycle phases (you need to consider maven as a state machine), maven allows bind plugins (actually plugin's goals) to lifecycle phases, so, in that case to execute lifecycle phase maven needs to download plugin(s) bound to particular lifecycle and it's dependencies

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same error `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-maven-plugin:2.27.1:check (spotless-check) on project flink-examples-batch_2.12: The following files had format violations:` while building Flink examples
[image]
[image]

I used the below command to check spotless

```
E:\Flink\flink-master1\flink-examples>mvn spotless:check
```

Then I ran the command '`mvn spotless:apply`' to fix these violations.

```
E:\Flink\flink-master1\flink-examples>mvn spotless:apply
E:\Flink\flink-master1\flink-examples>mvn clean package
```

[image]